# Gcc, binutils and minimal support version of glibc?

Tags: gcc, glibc, toolchain, binutils, gnu-toolchain

How I can to know what is a minimal version of glibc for gcc or binutils?

Regards.

Comment: Search for "glibc" in https://gcc.gnu.org/install/specific.html .

Answer (score 1):

binutils doesn't generally have a minimal glibc requirement because it doesn't have too much glibc-specific details in it.  it's merely a collection of low level tools like an assembler and linker and objdumper all of which are built on code included in binutils.

gcc is a different beast -- it needs to know intimate details about C library capabilities.  in the specific version of gcc you have, consult the `INSTALL/index.html` file (and particularly, the **Prerequisites** page) for the requirements.